# Different names of libxalanMsg.so in RPM's Provides and Requires

Tags: shared-libraries, rpm

I have an ELF binary linked against libxalanMsg.so. LibxalanMsg.so doesn't have a DT_SONAME entry so the binary has the library's linker name (libxalanMsg.so) in its DT_NEEDED. LibxalanMsg.so and libxalanMsg.so.111 are symlinks to libxalanMsg.so.111.0 as usual.

Now when I build an RPM from this binary I see that with regard to this library the package provides only "libxalanMsg.so.111.0()(64bit)" but requires "libxalanMsg.so()(64bit)". This difference in the names results in an unsatisfied dependency when the package is installed.

If I run find-provides manually the name is there:

```
[rpmbuild@localhost lib]$ echo `ls libxalanMsg.so*` | /usr/lib/rpm/find-provides
libxalanMsg.so.111.0()(64bit)
libxalanMsg.so.111()(64bit)
libxalanMsg.so()(64bit)
[rpmbuild@localhost lib]$
```

Why doesn't RPM put libxalanMsg.so in the Provides of the package? How should I make the package install successfully?